# Ignore all warnings from a module

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, librosa

i'm having some problems with librosa python module. It shows me the following warning at import.

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/pox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py:9: NumbaDeprecationWarning: An import was requested from a module that has moved location.
Import of 'jit' requested from: 'numba.decorators', please update to use 'numba.core.decorators' or pin to Numba version 0.48.0. This alias will not be present in Numba version 0.50.0.
  from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
```

since my code seems to work fine i just would like to don't show this warning anymore (i tried to fix it but i couldn't). 
I have tried to use warnings module like so

```
import librosa
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but the same warning is shown.
(i'm using anaconda python's 3.6 virtual enviroment)

Comment: You can just try to update the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import warnings
from numba.errors import NumbaPerformanceWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=NumbaPerformanceWarning)
```

If the above doesn't work:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: nothing works, with the first it gave me the same error x3

Comment: I cannot reproduce your warning, you may have to post more of your code or update the python packages.

Comment: it is very strange because i have created the enviroment this morning, the module should be at the latest version. is used: conda install librosa

Comment: try uninstalling the conda version and installing via `pip install librosa`

Comment: Try opening a new issue on [github](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues)

Comment: opened it, i'll mark your answer as correct because in most of the cases it will work

Comment: @Giuppox Appreciated, GL!

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)